# C++ - inclusion of typedef struct from inside a class

Tags: c++, struct, include

My question is about the inclusion of a typedef struct (or at least I think it is). It's probably silly but I couldn't figure out what's wrong with my code.

I have a `Node.h` header that declares a class `Node`:

```
class Node {
public:
    Node(/*some parameters*/); // Class constructor

    typedef struct{ // This represents a weighted edge of weight "weight" from the current node to another node "node"
        Node* node;
        double weight;
    }EdgeInfo;

    vector<EdgeInfo*> OutEdges; // This vector represents the outgoing weighted edges from this node
};
```

So I figured out that's the only place in my code I can declare the `struct` because that's the only place where I can declare `EdgeInfo` that "knows" what a `Node` class object is.

Then I have a `Graph.h` header, including the `Node.h` file, that declares a `Graph` class.

Now in the `Graph.cpp` file I'm implementing a function that loops on all the outgoing edges of a `Node`, more or less like this:

```
Node* current = /*passing an object of class Node*/

for(EdgeInfo* out : current->OutEdges){           
    /*working on the edges*/
}
```

The problem is that when I compile I get the error `error: ‘EdgeInfo’ was not declared in this scope` at the `for` loop.

As you probably can see I'm kind of a C++ newbie. I thought that by including `Node.h` I could use the ´typedef struct` definitions inside the class the same way I use variables and functions. Am I wrong? Or didn't I understand how includes work in C++?

I hope I didn't miss any detail. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: `Node::EdgeInfo`. But why do you use a `typedef` at that point at all? They're not necessary in C++ (in that context usually).

Comment: @Zeta Why? What would you do instead?

Comment: @Tommaso Scarpa In c++ you don't need to use the keyword `typedef` to declare a `struct`, or a `class`. It's valid but not necessary. You can just declare your `struct` by doing :  `struct S { int a; };` And you declare a instance of `struct S` by doing : `S s; s.a = 10`

Comment: @nikau6 I tried but if I remove `typedef` my code doesn't compile

Comment: @Tommaso Scarpa You must declare your `struct` like that : `struct S {};`, if you do what I think you do : `struct {}S;` it'll not compile.

Comment: @nikau6 Oh, you're right! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"*So I figured out that's the only place in my code I can declare the struct because that's the only place where I can declare EdgeInfo that "knows" what a Node class object is.*"

You could use a [forward declaration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class#Forward_declaration). A another link:  [forward declaration, stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757565/what-are-forward-declarations-in-c).

```
class Node; // forward declaration

struct EdgeInfo
{ 
    Node* node; // now, `EdgeInfo` knows that a class named `Node` is defined somewhere.
    double weight;
};

class Node {
public:
    Node(/*some parameters*/); // Class constructor

    vector<EdgeInfo*> OutEdges; // This vector represents the outgoing weighted edges from this node
};
```

Now when you include `node.h` in `graph.cpp`, or `Graph.h`, it'll be aware about `EdgeInfo`.